# How do I change the position of a radio button in html?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am programming a webpage that uses a series of radio buttons and drop down menus to change the data that is displayed on the screen. Each radio corresponds to one of the drop down menus and I want to line them up but I can't figure out how to get the third one to appear to the right of the other two instead of below them. Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
<form action="" style="float: left">
<input type="radio" name="yearLessGreaterOption" value="<" onchange="setYearLessGreaterFilter(this.value)"><
<input type="radio" name="yearLessGreaterOption" value="=" onchange="setYearLessGreaterFilter(this.value)" checked>=
<input type="radio" name="yearLessGreaterOption" value=">" onchange="setYearLessGreaterFilter(this.value)">>
</form>

<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="roundLessGreaterOption" value="<" onchange="setRoundLessGreaterFilter(this.value)"><
<input type="radio" name="roundLessGreaterOption" value="=" onchange="setRoundLessGreaterFilter(this.value)" checked>=
<input type="radio" name="roundLessGreaterOption" value=">" onchange="setRoundLessGreaterFilter(this.value)">>
</form>

<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="goalsH1LessGreaterOption" value="<" onchange="setGoalsH1LessGreaterFilter(this.value)"><
<input type="radio" name="goalsH1LessGreaterOption" value="=" onchange="setGoalsH1LessGreaterFilter(this.value)" checked>=
<input type="radio" name="goalsH1LessGreaterOption" value=">" onchange="setGoalsH1LessGreaterFilter(this.value)">>
</form>
```

Here's a picture of the page in question:

[image]

Comment: Maybe add `style="float: left;"` to the second `form` just like you did on the first one?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you want them in form tags? If you remove the tags, they will appear aligned. Otherwise, adding `style="float:left;"` to the other form tags will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, adding the `style="float: left"` on the other forms should do what you want.